# Transactional Replication between Azure DB server and On-Premises DB servers

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have seen some articles regarding replication of data between master db and slave db. Is it possible to do so on azure and on premises db also ?

I mean can the both Db's be synced for any changes in Db's ?